# How to enable debug mode for Docker client on Windows 10?

Tags: docker, windows

By default, Docker client is not in debug mode. How to enable it?

```
   > docker info

    ..
    Debug Mode (client): false
    Debug Mode (server): true
    ..
```

If I try following `docker --help`

```
docker -D version
```

I get indeed

```
Debug Mode (client): true
Debug Mode (server): true
```

But then, how can I access log messages? The following for example does not seem to bring any debug statements to the console:

```
PS U:\> docker -D -l debug pull ubuntu:16.04
16.04: Pulling from library/ubuntu
75c416ea735c: Pull complete
c6ff40b6d658: Pull complete
a7050fc1f338: Pull complete
f0ffb5cf6ba9: Pull complete
be232718519c: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:a0ee7647e24c8494f1cf6b94f1a3cd127f4
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:16.04
```

Comment: Try `docker -D info`, by default it is not enabled and the client is the command you just run...

Comment: you are right - as you suggested, I get "true" for the client as well; but where would I see the debug output for docker pull?

Comment: "docker -D -l debug" - but where do the log messages go?..

Comment: okay please check the updated question.

Comment: Ok, sorry for misunderstanding. docker pull has a special case according to this [issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/6927)

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, using the `docker -D -l debug` setting for the client  I have found the log outputs (apparently currently there are no debug level messages implemented [as reported](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/6927).

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Docker\log.txt
```